# Close all but first Chrome windows with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

I would like to close all chrome windows (not tabs - just to be clear) **except the first opened** and i think that could happen with powershell script. I tried with CMD but it's a nightmare. [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754230/closing-all-explorer-windows-in-powershell) is very similar, but i can't adapt it for my case.

Comment: Yeah that could happen with a powershell script. Please show what you tried so far and where it failed :)
Take a look at [ask] and offer a [mcve]. We are not here to do all the work for you ;)

Comment: The thing is that i cannot start. I think that the first step should be to get a list of all active windows. And here is where i am failing :(

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the `Get-Process`
You can display all properties, if you pipe the CMDLet with select: `Get-Process | select *`
There are many usefull properties you can use for your project, like ProcessName, StartTime,TotalProcessorTime, MainWindowTitle etc.

Heres an example howe you get all open chrome windows

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -eq "chrome" -and $_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""}
```